# Inverse fourier transform

Tags: matlab, signals, fft, ifft

I'm trying to write IFT algorithm. Here is my code:

```
%% Fourier Analysis
N = 20;
T1 = 0.25*N;
T0 = N;
x = [zeros(T1,1); ones(T0/2,1); zeros(T1,1)]';

omega = 2*pi*1/T0;

ak = zeros(1,2*N+1);

for k = -N:N
    if k == 0
        ak(k+N+1) = 2*T1/T0;
    else
        ak(k+N+1) = sin(k*omega*T1)/(k*pi);
    end
end

%Approximate the periodic symmetric square wave
t=linspace(-0.5,0.5,N);

for n=1:length(t)
    xN(n)=0;
    for k = -N:N
        xN(n) = xN(n) + ak(k+N+1).*exp(1i*k*omega*t(n));
    end
end
```

What's wrong with it (I know that Matlab have ifft() function, but I would like to write my own)? I use for it this code:

[image: ift]

The result should looks like (EN is error):

[image]

Where black plot is xN and blue plot is x. My result is straight line.

Comment: "What's wrong with it" - you tell us - in what way is it not doing what you expect ?

Comment: I expect result as with ifft() function. It should approximate the periodic symmetric square wave (x) by considering only a finite
number of the Fourier series coefficients.

Comment: How is the result different from the `ifft` function?

Comment: Any suggestions where are mistakes?

Comment: can you please do fft and ifft and plot that with respect to your solution? Because if those plots are your implementation, then it looks correct as far as what I would expect to see.

Comment: There results aren't show my implementation. I takes it from books.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know where you got that formula in the image from, but for an `N`-point fourier transform of a discrete signal, you only need to sum over `k` from `0` to `N-1` to get an exact reconstruction. `N` orthogonal basis functions can reconstruct any `N`-dimensional signal. You might be confusing the [DTFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete-time_Fourier_transform) with the [DFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) (you want the second of these).

I also don't understand the formulas you used for the `ak` coefficients. You calculate them with `sin` and then sum them up with complex exponentials rather than sine waves.

If you want to do a discrete fourier transform (DFT) with a complex exponentials, the code should look similar to mine below. You get the `ck` coefficients from the inner product of the time signal `x` and the complex basis functions.

```
clear; clc;

N = 20;                                        %// number of points

x = [zeros(1,N/4),ones(1,N/2),zeros(1,N/4)];   %//time signal data
n = 0:N-1;

ck = zeros(1,N);
for k = 0:N-1                                  %//cacluate coefficients
    ck(k+1) = sum(x.*exp(-1i*2*pi*k*n/N));
end

xN = zeros(1,N);
for k = 0:N-1                                  %// add partial frequencies
    xN = xN + ck(k+1)*exp(1i*2*pi*k*n/N)/N;
end

plot(n,xN)
```

[image]

---

If you want to do an ordinary fourier series using real sinusoids, your code should look like this:

```
clear; clc;

N = 20;                                         %// number of points
T = 1;                                          %// fundamental frequency
omega = 2*pi/T;                                 %// angular frequency

t = linspace(-0.5,0.5,N);                       %// time points
x = [zeros(1,N/4),ones(1,N/2),zeros(1,N/4)];    %// time signal data

a0 = sum(x)/N;  ak = zeros(1,N);    bk = zeros(1,N);
for k = 1:N-1                                   %// calculate coefficients
    ak(k) = sum(x.*cos(omega*k*t))/N;
    bk(k) = sum(x.*sin(omega*k*t))/N;
end

xN = a0*cos(omega*0*t);                         %// add DC offset
for k = 1:N-1                                   %// add partial frequencies
    xN = xN + ak(k)*cos(omega*k*t) + bk(k)*sin(omega*k*t);
end

plot(t,xN)
```

Comment: I take it from http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=47916931294804743910 (8th page).

Comment: @Kulis I see, you have the right idea in your original code, then. It seems they want you to treat `x(t)` as a real-time signal. This means you should sample `t` very finely; use far more than `N` time points, `t = linspace(-0.5,0.5,1000);`, for example. Also, set `omega = 2*pi;` since the range of our signal is `[-0.5,0.5]`, so a fundamental period of `T=1` should be used. Hopefully that gets your code working.

Comment: Yeah, It works perfectly. I change t and omega.